# C++: Memory maps / Caching libraries?

Tags: c++, caching, memory-management, mmap, hpc

**Can anybody recommend a library that makes caching/memory maps easy-to-use?**

Memory management is *not* the focus of my project - it is a last-minute issue I am running into.  Hence, I am looking for a relatively quick-and-easy fix rather than trying to learn all the details of caching and memory maps.

I am looking for a library that will automatically (under-the-hood) write and load (cache) from a file.

---

Ideally, I am looking for the following: I can simply access/insert/delete from a "map" without having to save/load from a file.  If my `std::map` is relatively small, than this is directly from the heap.  If my `map` becomes to large, then it is memory mapped, and all load/save (from the mmap file) functions are performed "under the hood", so that I still only hve to do  `mymap.find(whatever)` , etc.

(Each node in my multi-processor program produces a large amount of computations.  When I try to `all_gather`, the program crashes.  No single node has enough memory to hold the results of all the nodes combined.  Thus, I am looking for some sort of memory map / caching strategy.)

---

This is run on a supercomputer (so, OS = UNIX).  Each node has 16GB memory.  There is a scratch space (enormous space for writing temporary files) that uses eSATA.  (I envision effective memory mapping to this scratch space as a solution)

Comment: Would something like [stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) suffice?

Comment: What do you need to do with the data? Just collect some data from each node and dump it into a file, or you need to first combine the data from all the nodes into a single one, process it and then dump it into a file?

Comment: BTW, isn't swapping exactly doing what you are mentioning?

Comment: The data from each node is combined (but not reduced) - sort of analogous to a Cartesian product.  Each node uses these  new values for further computations.  Those combined values are identical on each node.

Comment: Possibly;  I am not sure what swapping is, though.  I'm not a computer scientist by trade...

Comment: If you can't load all the stuff into memory, swap over to streaming, if speed doesn't matter increase the swap space to the data size you work with, otherwise try stxxl. Can you maybe explain where the real problem lies, if your memorymap is too big to be loaded into memory or if you have multiple processes loading such memory maps? Please be aware that the size of the loaded data for shared memory and the like has to be defined in the configuration of your OS for Linux: /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: [8 GB Physical Memory][8 GB SWAP] Your program can now use more than 8 GB of memory, Swap space is like "Ram on Disk" the operating system is writing unused blocks down to disk so that the memory is now available for your programm

Comment: @OliverStutz not sure what swapping is, either :(.    The problem is that I have multiple "pieces" of a map that need to be combined into one larger map.  This larger map is too big for memory, apparently (always run out of heap space while combining).  So I need the map to be on file and to read off values from the map, when necessary...

Comment: Are you sure your problem is physical memory rather than address space?

Comment: @JoeGauterin  I don't know...  BOOST MPI throws the error `what():  MPI_Alloc_mem: MPI_ERR_NO_MEM: out of memory`

Comment: @CycoMatto maybe this Link helps http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/v.html it has an illustration which can show you how this works. Do you have the code for this cartesian product under your control? What is the map size for each? What OS are you running? That might make it possible for us to help you better.

Comment: @OliverStutz  Yes, I wrote the Cartesian product-esque code.  Also, I updated the question with the system specs.  The map size is order O(10k) - O(100k).  I will check out the link, thank you!

Comment: @KillianDS  Are there any caveats for using STXXL with MPI tha you know of?

Comment: @OliverStutz  Are there any caveats for using STXXL with MPI tha you know of?

Comment: @CycoMatto If you can write the cartesian product directly to disk, this would be the best to do, you wrote that the map1 contains 10k and map2 100k, whats the size of the records in bytes? Check your swap with fdisk -l, downsides of STXXL -> you have to compile another library, it is made for "Big-Data" in other words it might perform not as good on smaller data sets (more overhead/maintaining)